# Is there a way to make masonry layouts in css with varied div sizes

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, masonry

Ideally I would like to make a layout that has automatically sized rows and columns that fits the div sizes. I want to achieve something like this [Ideal Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKuGe.png).
Where each div is its own size and automatically gets fit into space if there's some available. Each other div is then wrapped at the end of the element above it. If this isn't possible with just CSS that's fine too I would still like to know how to get started with it in JavaScript. Thanks!

Comment: Are you actually aiming for the layout you show or is that just an example? It seems to have several limits - basically a 3 column by 9 column grid but I guess you want something completely general? CSS is coming with masonry but not there yet. See https://css-tricks.com/piecing-together-approaches-for-a-css-masonry-layout/ for various ideas given the current CSS limitations.

Comment: Yeah, it's just an example. I've taken a look at that site before and it's not quite what I want but thanks for your help anyway!